# Ember Data query filtering doesn't work with Firebase

Tags: firebase, ember.js, firebase-realtime-database, ember-data

Suppose that I have the following data in Firebase Database

```
{
  "carros" : {
    "-LAy3Qqrvq_sIhyLJQED" : {
      "añoFabricacion" : 1932,
      "marca" : "toyota",
      "nombre" : "nombre1"
    },
    "-LAy3r-Gm_NWW9_VkGR3" : {
      "añoFabricacion" : 1931,
      "marca" : "audi",
      "nombre" : "nombre2"
    },
    "-LAy3v9L2wecTDZqpok9" : {
      "añoFabricacion" : 1934,
      "marca" : "toyota",
      "nombre" : "nombre3"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to print in console the attribute "nombre" of the objects whose "marca" attribute is equals to "toyota". I wrote a controller code as follows:

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    mostrar() {
      this.get('store').query('carro', {
        filter: {
          marca: 'toyota'
        }
      }).then(function(carros) {
        carros.forEach(function(carro) {
          console.log(carro.get('nombre'));
        })
      });
    }
  }
});
```

And the corresponding code for the model "carro.js" is:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  nombre: DS.attr('string'),
  marca: DS.attr('string'),
  añoFabricacion: DS.attr('number')
});
```

The problem is that I am obtaining the following output:

```
nombre1
nombre2
nombre3
```

But the correct output must be:

```
nombre1
nombre3
```

Why I am getting this error?

Comment: Ember Data simply adds the query object as stringified JSON to the query string, so you'll need to work out what firebase accepts.  Suggest you use Ember Fire and take a look at https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/blob/master/docs/guide/querying-data.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the documentation here: https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/ember-js/ember-extended/firebase-queries

it looks like the correct query is as follows:

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    mostrar() {
      this.get('store').query('carro', {
        orderBy: 'marca'
        equalTo: 'toyota'
      }).then(function(carros) {
        carros.forEach(function(carro) {
          console.log(carro.get('nombre'));
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```